# MPI error with incompatible parameter types "char" to "const char" c++

Tags: c++, types

My program generates random symbols and writes them to a text file. Code below generates random symbols:

```
static const char alphanum[] =
"0123456789"
"!@#$%^&*"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int stringLength = sizeof(alphanum) - 1;
char genRandom()
{
return alphanum[rand() % stringLength];
}
```

In code below there is created mpi thread and text file.  from this code line that writes random symbols `fprintf(fp, genRandom());` I get error " `argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"` and `C2664` error

```
int num;
MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &num);

int a;
char filename[1000];
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &a);
sprintf(filename, "file.txt", a);
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");

if (num){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, genRandom()); // genRandom() - gives me error because different char types 
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
MPI_Finalize();
```

Comment: I'm removing the MPI tag as the problem has basically zero relation to message passing. `fprintf` is a function from the standard C library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write `fprintf(fp, "%c", genRandom());`

That is you need to supply a format string. Currently the compiler thinks you are passing no variable arguments, and is attempting to convert `genRandom()` into the format string (with type `const char*`) and raises an error accordingly. (Did the error actually say `const char*` - note the `*`?)